# Odoo: Inherit: Replace field conditionally

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo

I want to do something that I've never done before and really don't have any ideas on how to solve it.

What I want to do is:
When a checkbox is checked, replace a field "name" with another (selection)field, but write the value to the original field "name".

The problem here is when I do an inherit with replace like this:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="replace">
            <field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('realman', '=', True)]}"/>                
            <field name="workcenter_naam" attrs="{'invisible': [('realman', '=', False)]}" required="1"/>
</xpath>
```

(In this code, field "realman" is the checkbox.)

It will look correct in the front end, but when I choose a value for the field "workcenter_naam" and click save, it gives this error:

> The following fields are invalid: Name

If I change the name of the field "workcenter_naam" to "name" in the python file, it will ALWAYS use that field (instead of the original name field), independant of that checkbox. Like this:

```
workcenter_naam = fields.Selection(_workcentername_selection, string="Workcenter naam")
```

Instead of:

```
name = fields.Selection(_workcentername_selection, string="Workcenter naam")
```

This is what it looks like in the front end:
[image]

How it looks like in the front end, is how it should.
The value chosen in the inherited view, for example "Bakkerij", just needs to be put in the name field.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue? If there is anything unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the field "name" is invisible but it is still required

You can keep both fields, but you should remove the attribute "required" in the "name" field of your python class. Finally add the attribute "required" to the xml form view to make it required only in that specific view:

```xml
<field name="name" position="replace">
    <field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('realman', '=', True)]}" required="1"/>                
    <field name="workcenter_naam" attrs="{'invisible': [('realman', '=', False)]}" required="1"/>
</field>
```

Or you can do what you have done :)

```
@api.onchange('workcenter_naam')
def onchange_workcenter_naam(self):
    self.name = self.workcenter_naam
```

And I would also add this function (or similar) in order to reset the "name" field

```
@api.onchange('realman')
def onchange_realman(self):
    if self.realman:
        self.name = self.workcenter_naam            
    else:
        self.name = ''
        self.workcenter_naam = self._defaults['workcenter_naam']
```

Comment: You are right. But since it gives this error I know the value for "workcenter_naam" isn't passed to the field "name".
I want my field to overwrite the field "name", ONLY IF realman = true.

Comment: OK, then you can add a compute function which stores the value of `workcenter_naam` in the field `name`

Comment: I've solved it now. Very easy...
@api.onchange('workcenter_naam')
And in the function: self.name = self.workcenter_naam

Comment: I edited my answer in order to close the question. Check if it is right and if you like the reset function that I added